# Basis of a Cyclotomic Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've started learning algebraic number theory when I found something that confused me; for a prime $p$, where $\zeta=e^{(2\pi i/p)}$, a primitive $p$-th root of unity. Then the extension $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$ has basis $\{1,\zeta,\zeta^2...\zeta^{p-2}\}$. Could someone explain why the basis doesn't contain all $p$ roots? And was the choice of not including $\zeta^{p-1}$ arbitrary, or did it have to be that root in particular? I suppose it's naive of me, but it seemed intuitive that the basis would need all roots.

Comment: Two cautions: (1) “intuition” is a poor guide in mathematics, as it is in learning a new language; (2) in mathematics, Nothing is True, unless there’s a proof that it’s true. In your case, you should look at very simple cases to see why the set you expected is not linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\phi(p)=p-1$, so the basis must contain $p-1$ elements. And observe that
$$ 1+\zeta_p+\zeta_p^2+\dots+\zeta_p^{p-2}+\zeta_p^{p-1}=\frac{1-\zeta_p^p}{1-\zeta_p}=0 $$
so $\zeta_p^{p-1}=-(1+\zeta_p+\zeta_p^2+\dots+\zeta_p^{p-2})$. This relation also shows that any other root $\zeta_p^k$ could have been excluded.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial for $\zeta_p$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $$x^{p-1}+x^{p-2} + \cdots + x +1.$$

Plugging in $\zeta_p$, we have
$$\zeta_p^{p-1} + \zeta_p^{p-2} + \cdots + \zeta_p +1=0.$$

So,
$$\zeta^{p-1}= -\zeta_p^{p-2} - \cdots - \zeta_p - 1.$$

Therefore,
$$\zeta_p^{p-1} \in \mathrm{span}\{1, \zeta_p, \zeta_p^2, \dots, \zeta_p^{p-2}\}.$$